# Python: replace values of sublist, with values looked up from another sublist without indexing

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, replace

### Description

I have two lists of lists which are derived from CSVs (minimal working example below). The real dataset for this too large to do this manually.

```
mainlist = [["MH75","QF12",0,38], ["JQ59","QR21",105,191], ["JQ61","SQ48",186,284], ["SQ84","QF36",0,123], ["GA55","VA63",80,245], ["MH98","CX12",171,263]]

replacelist = [["MH75","QF12","BA89","QR29"], ["QR21","JQ59","VA51","MH52"],  ["GA55","VA63","MH19","CX84"], ["SQ84","QF36","SQ08","JQ65"], ["SQ48","JQ61","QF87","QF63"], ["MH98","CX12","GA34","GA60"]]
```

- `mainlist` contains a pair of identifiers (`mainlist[x][0]`, `mainlist[x][1]`) and these are associated with to two integers (`mainlist[x][2]` and `mainlist[x][3]`).
- `replacelist` is a second list of lists which also contains the same pairs of identifiers (but not in the same order within a pair, or across rows). All sublist pairs are unique.  **Importantly,** `replacelist[x][2],replacelist[x][3]` corresponds to a replacement for `replacelist[x][0],replacelist[x][1]`, respectively.
- I need to create a new third list, `newlist` which copies `mainlist` *but* replaces the identifiers with those from `replacelist[x][2],replacelist[x][3]`

For example, given:
`mainlist[2]` is: `[JQ61,SQ48,186,284]`
The matching pair in replacelist is
`replacelist[4]: [SQ48,JQ61,QF87,QF63]`
Therefore the expected output is 
`newlist[2] = [QF87,QF63,186,284]`

More clearly put:
if replacelist = [[A, B, C, D]] 
A is replaced with C, and B is replaced with D.
but it may appear in mainlist as [[B, A]]

*Note newlist row position uses the same as mainlist*

### Attempt

What has me totally stumped on a simple problem is I feel I can't use basic list comprehension `[i for i in replacelist if i in mainlist]` as the order within a pair changes, and if I `sorted(list)` then I lose information about what to replace the lists with. Current solution (with commented blanks):

```
newlist = []
for k in replacelist:
    for i in mainlist:
        if k[0] and k[1] in i:
            # retrieve mainlist order, then use some kind of indexing to check a series of nested if statements to work out positional replacement.
```

As you can see, this solution is clearly inefficient and I can't work out the best way to perform the final step in a few lines.

*I can add more information if this is not clear*

Comment: Sounds like you might need a dictreader. Also, sample data would be *infinitely* more useful. And sample (desired) output, rather than how it is you're trying to solve it. You might want to re-read what makes a [mcve].

Comment: @WayneWerner thanks I will update values to be more human readable now

Comment: Does `replacelist = [[A, B, C, D]]` mean that `A` is replaced with `C`, and `B` is replaced with `D`?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Yes sorry, I should have made that more clear.

Comment: @MichaelAnderson I get a `NameError` when I paste that into my interpreter. This *still* isn't an MCVE.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you do - transform both lists in a dictionary:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

maindct = OrderedDict((frozenset(item[:2]),item[2:]) for item in mainlist)
replacedct = {frozenset(item[:2]):item[2:] for item in replacementlist}

# Now it is trivial to create another dict with the desired output:
output_list = [replacedct[key] + maindct[key] for key in maindct]
```

The big deal here is that by using a dictionary, you cancel up the search time for the indices on the replacement list - in a  list you have to scan all the list for each item you have, which makes your performance worse with the square of your list length. With Python dictionaries, the search time is constant - and do not depend on the data length at all.

Comment: sorting the key-tuples: `tuple(sorted(item[:2])):item[2:] ` will work better as the order of the two identifiers may vary

Comment: Yeah I was about to ask, I had avoided dictionaries as the order of the rows is very important. I was unsure how Python 3 deals with that?

Thankyou very much, I will test this soon.

Comment: If the order of the rows is important, you can fix it by using an ordereddict- I will  change the answer to reflect that.

Comment: And yes - my first answer used unsorted tuples which were wrong  - I adopted the frozenset from @inspectorG4dget's answer, as the most appropriate data structure here.

Answer (score 1):

It'll help if you had `replacelist` as a dict:

```
mainlist = [[MH75,QF12,0,38], [JQ59,QR21,105,191], [JQ61,SQ48,186,284], [SQ84,QF36,0,123], [GA55,VA63,80,245], [MH98,CX12,171,263]]

replacelist = [[MH75,QF12,BA89,QR29], [QR21,JQ59,VA51,MH52],  [GA55,VA63,MH19,CX84], [SQ84,QF36,SQ08,JQ65], [SQ48,JQ61,QF87,QF63], [MH98,CX12,GA34,GA60]]

replacements = {frozenset(r[:2]):dict(zip(r[:2], r[2:])) for r in replacements}

newlist = []
for *ids, val1, val2 in mainlist:
    reps = replacements[frozenset([id1, id2])]
    newlist.append([reps[ids[0]], reps[ids[1]], val1, val2])
```